# unbind does not really work : is there any other solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unbind

i'm trying to "stop" the click action on #mydiv, i mean if i click 100 times on #mydiv i would like the opacity to happen just once, not 100 times, i found this solution on the web with "unbind", i think it worked the first time i used it, but now it does not work, it might be a simple mistake, but i don't really know where to look at. I commented all my jquery page, i just have the document ready line and those 2 functions, but it does not stop the action on the click :

```
$('#mydiv').bind('click', function() {
  $('.myclass').animate(opacity: 0.25);
});

$('#mydiv').unbind('click', function() {
    $('.myclass').animate(opacity: 0.25);
});
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery 1.7+ :

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', anim);

$('#mydiv').off('click', anim);


function anim() {
    $('.myclass').animate(opacity: 0.25);
}
```

You could even do:

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', anim);

function anim() {
    $('.myclass').animate(opacity: 0.25);
    $('#mydiv').off('click', anim);
}
```

or

```
$('#mydiv').one("click", function() {
    $('.myclass').animate(opacity: 0.25);
});
```

And of course it should be:

```
$('.myclass').animate({opacity: 0.25}, speed);
```

Comment: @Miles_Crew, don't forget to "accept" the best answer.  IMHO, this one is it because it recognizes `on()` as the new preferred method.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use:

```
$('#mydiv').unbind('click');
```

Or

If you want to the click to happen only once, use `one` instead:

```
$('#mydiv').one(function() {
  $('.myclass').animate(opacity: 0.25);
});
```